# Locate and Move files to a destination

Tags: bash

I intend to locate some files matching a certain pattern. After the files have been located, i want to move them to a new directory.

```
for i in $(find <search_location> -name '<search_pattern>')
do
    #mkdir -p <new_location_to_be_copied_to>
    mv $i <new_location_to_be_copied_to>
done
```

Can the above code achieve that.
Any better way to achieve that?

---

### UPDATE

After Executing the above, some abnormalities were observed. The search string inputted was not correctly filtered.

scenario:

1. search string : ABA
2. Some item list:
   ABA-LND-21052021.jpg
   IKS-ABA-18022020.jpg
3. Result: Moved both items to destination folder
4. Expected Result: Move only ABA-LND-21052021.jpg to destination Folder

Comment: Did you try to implement this? What were the difficulties? // Questions seeking **installation, configuration or diagnostic help** must include [the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/3608). Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: I didn't test this. I do not have a test environment as at when the question was posted.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to create the folder before the loop if it's the same (optimisations are everywhere :D )

So, I have the following (tested on Ubuntu 18.04) :

```
mkdir -p <destination_folder>
for i in $(find <source_folder> -name '<pattern>')
do
    mv $i <destination_folder>
done
```